# Import nested Typescript module

Tags: module, typescript, commonjs

I have got the type definition file for a library - seneca. I don't know know how to import this module into typescript source.

I have used

```
/// <reference path="../custom_typings/seneca.d.ts" />
```

Please see the below [seneca.d.ts](https://gist.github.com/psnider/0afa89e1bd2992756e55) file

I want to use the add(..) function in the seneca module.

Answer (score 0):

Just add it to the `module s` e.g.

```
    module s {
      export var add:Function; // Sample
```

Comment: ok, but, we have the add function declaration inside an interface in module `s`, not directly in module `s`. Did you check out the seneca.d.ts  file?

Comment: I checked your comment there with you trying to call `seneca.add`. If that is the call you need to make then this is the definition you need.

Comment: ok, i will go with that. Thanks for the help. I really appreciate.